# How to turn a two element direction tuple left or right (Snake game)?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm coding a snake game AI and have the following problem. I'm getting the next `move` 1 (turn right) or -1 (turn left) from my AI class. And I need to turn my snake according to them. I have my snake's `direction` encoded as the following:

> `(1, 0)  => going right`
>
> `(-1, 0) => going left`
>
> `(0, -1) => going up`
>
> `(0, 1)  => going down`

Is there any way to simplify the following `if-elif` block so I don't need to check every single combination by hand?

```
if move == 1:
    if snake.direction == (1, 0):
        snake.direction = (0, 1)

    elif snake.direction == (-1, 0):
        snake.direction = (0, -1)

    elif snake.direction == (0, 1):
        snake.direction = (-1, 0)

    elif snake.direction == (0, -1):
        snake.direction = (1, 0)

elif move == -1:
    if snake.direction == (1, 0):
        snake.direction = (0, -1)

    elif snake.direction == (-1, 0):
        snake.direction = (0, 1)

    elif snake.direction == (0, 1):
        snake.direction = (1, 0)

    elif snake.direction == (0, -1):
        snake.direction = (-1, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

```
import numpy as np

def update_direction (m, move):
    return tuple(np.flip((np.array(m) * move) * np.array([1, -1]), 0))
```

---

However, have you though about using a more simplified direction representation?

For example just have a single variable `direction` have a possible range of 0 to 3 `(0 == North, 1 == East, 2 == South, 3 == West)`. That way when you want to turn you just add a `turn` value of either 1 or -1.

```
# Function updates direction
def update_direction(snake, turn):
    return snake.direction = (snake.direction + turn) % 4

# turn left
update_direction(snake, -1)

# turn right
update_direction(snake, 1)
```

You could then turn this logic into a method for the snake to be most effective.

Answer (score 3):

You can use linear algebra to help you solve this problem. Using numpy you can multiply your direction vector by the appropriate rotation matrix:

```
import numpy as np

if move == -1:
    rot_mat = np.array([[0, -1], [1, 0]])
elif move == 1:
    rot_mat = np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])
```

These are the mathematical matrices which when taking the dot product with your velocity (direction) vectors will give you the new direction vector of travel.

```
snake.direction = tuple(np.array(snake.direction).dot(rot_mat))
```

Or if you want to condense it even further you can do the whole thing in one line of code

```
snake.direction = tuple(np.array(snake.direction).dot(move * np.array([[0, 1], [-1, 0]])))
```